# jQuery .val not updating DOM on input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

So i seem to have found a problem im not sure if this is jQuery bug or it's just not possible but if any one has managed this could they tell me how.

I have a Date picker and i don't want to allow users to select dates in the past.

```
var d = new Date($(this).val());
var nowDate = new Date();
var nowDateParse = ""+
    nowDate.getFullYear()+
    (nowDate.getMonth()+1 < 10? "0"+(nowDate.getMonth()+1): (nowDate.getMonth()+1))+
    (nowDate.getDate()+1 < 10? "0"+(nowDate.getDate()+1): (nowDate.getDate()+1));
var selDate = ""+
    d.getFullYear()+
    (d.getMonth()+1 < 10? "0"+(d.getMonth()+1): (d.getMonth()+1))+
    (d.getDate()+1 < 10? "0"+(d.getDate()+1): (d.getDate()+1));
if(parseInt(nowDateParse) > parseInt(selDate)){
    alert("You can only select dates in the future!");
    $("#searchDate").attr("value", ""+
        nowDate.getFullYear()+"-"
        (nowDate.getMonth()+1 < 10? "0"+(nowDate.getMonth()+1): (nowDate.getMonth()+1))+"-"+
        (nowDate.getDate()+1 < 10? "0"+(nowDate.getDate()+1): (nowDate.getDate()+1))
    )
    return false;
}
```

as you can see i have tired `$("#searchDate").attr("value"` as well as `$("#searchDate").val(` but both seem to cause the same problem.

So Date starts on the current date: 27/06/2016 (UK format for: 2016-06-27)

if the user selects a date before that E.G 26/06/2016 (UK format for: 2016-06-26)

it shows the alert but fails to change the date back to today's date.

I'm not against using Standard Javascript with out jQuery calls if thats what is needed.

**NOTES:::**

As a note this code looks quite complex due to the fact it's doing a date comparison and not a datetime comparison as Javascript's `Date` object is a datetime not just a date

Comment: Did you try to actually call `val()` method instead of `attr('value')`

Comment: your code is very complex. how about to use a time library? (e.g moment.js)

Comment: `minDate: 0` option should be fine for disabling past dates.

Comment: @jcubic yes i say that i have tried both in my question i tried `.val()` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this after the control of the date validity:

```js
    var dToday = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + dToday.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (dToday.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    today = dToday.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    $("#searchDate").val(today);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="searchDate">
```

Comment: this sets it but does not handle if the have selected a date in the past.

Comment: You said you can see the alert in case of the date selected is past today. Add this code after the alert and it should work

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now you said where to include it you might want to add that to your answer so anyone else with this problem can see what you mean i will accept as soon as i can 2 mins... :)

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new date object and set it as minDate when you initialize the datepickers

```
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>

var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/qvmqawfd/

Comment: i'm not using Date picker im using the HTML5 `input type="date"` as it's in cordova and i want to use the phones date picker not one in Javascript

Comment: i know it would but it's using jQuery UI datepicker not HTML5 date